# Use OdbcDataAdapter to select timestamp values

Tags: c#, oracle, timestamp, odbc, dataadapter

I'm trying to fill a DataTable from an Oracle database using an OdbcDataAdapter (Driver=Microsoft ODBC for Oracle).
The basic code is like this (minus functional OdbcConnection, instantiated DataTable, try and catch statements, etc.):

```
string queryString = "myquerystring"
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, odbcConnection);
adapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

My problem is that the Fill() method is throwing an exception which seems to be due to the fact that one of the columns I'm selecting is of type Timestamp.  I really only want a DateTime, but I don't care if the conversion happens before or after the Fill, as long as I can get the data into the program.  How do I configure the OdbcDataAdapter (or the DataTable?) to handle a timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not way how to do that. The Microsoft's one ODBC driver is very a old and it does not support "new" datatypes(like timestamp or blob). The only option is to install contemporary ODBC driver from Oracle.

Comment: Ok, good to know.  I do have an Oracle driver installed on my computer, it shows up in the ODBC administration window as "Oracle in OraClient 12Home1".  How can I integrate this into my code?  It doesn't work to simply substitute that name in the Driver part of the string.  Do I have to include some new "using" statement or is there a different driver name I'm supposed to use?
I can't install the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio because I'm using VS Express Edition.

Comment: You have to create a a new data source (DSN) using ODBC datasource administrator. Use new ODBC driver for this new datasource and then use the new datasource's name in your app.

Comment: I've defined the dsn now in ODBC and connecting works from there.  But I still can't find the driver from my program.

My connection string: "Driver={Oracle in OraClient 12Home1}; Dsn=<dsnname>;"

Getting the error, "Data source name not found and no default driver specified".  The driver name matches exactly the one displayed in my ODBC Manager, but doesn't seem to be detected - is there something wrong with my connection string?  I've already been to connectionstrings.com, but didn't get much help.

Comment: Update: Finally got around this by installing Oracle's ODBC driver, configuring the database info in tnsnames.ora and then linking each of them to an ODBC connection.  A bit complicated, but it's working now and I'm able to get out timestamps.

Comment: P.S. Thanks for your help: you answered my first question and helped me through the unexpected challenges that followed.
Can you confirm one thing: is it really impossible to use any database driver other than "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" with a connection string directly in the program?  The current solution is unwieldy when moving the program to other computers and I'd prefer a "cleaner" solution.  Or do I just have to use the full version of Visual Studio with ODT for VS?

Comment: I'm not sure. Officially Oracle forbids redistribution of their client libraries. You can also use instantclient (with ODBC) and anyay you will need Admin privs. to execute a command which will register the new ODBC driver with Windows system.